# cannot show map link in my website

Tags: google-maps, joomla

I created a website using prodecor template. I added google maps link in my code:

```
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1ahzfDqL1SGO8vUJqoV7i28JWRZs" width="1380" height="480"></iframe>
```

when I load http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_3.6.5-Stable-Full_Package_French_v1/?tp=1 (with ?tp=1) the map is loaded but when I remove ?tp=1 the map is no longer there.. I cannot find where the problem is.

Comment: Did you place this iframe in a module?

Comment: What do you mean by "I added .... in my code" ... what code where? I believe that the Joomla core contains a module called wrapper which will automatically display an iframe, that is the simplest thing to do.